# Force browser to use no cache does not seem to work for my site

Tags: php, caching

i have found this php code in another question to force my php script to reload webpage with no cache but does not seem to work. I am saving currency preference into a cookie and i need to force the webpage to reload using no cache. Any thoughts?

```
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: The following should work: header('Expires: 0'); header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate'); header('Pragma: no-cache');

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working i tried it.